# How do I add a timer to my gitlab-ci job to make it stop within 1 minute in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a spring boot application and I am configuring gitlab-ci.yml to run my integration tests. In order to achieve that I need my spring boot app running.

I am able to bring up my app using spring-boot-maven-plugin but the job I configured does not complete since the app is running and times out at 1 hour.

Is there a way to end a gitlab-ci job after a minute or two?

here is my gitlab-ci.yml config

```
server_start:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn spring-boot:start
```

Are there other examples of how to configure the gitlab-ci.yml to check if the server is up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout per job is currently unavailable. See [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18183)

You can define a 'global' [timeout](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#timeout):

> Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines settings

Comment: Thank you. Would have so convenient to have that functionality.